# Incorrect cursor movement in PuTTY when connected to Raspbian

Tags: ssh, terminal, putty, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've run into a very odd problem connecting to my Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian) using PuTTY for Windows — the ANSI "cursor" position isn't getting updated correctly.

This manifests in a couple of different ways that I've discovered so far.  The most obvious (and irritating) problem is that, when I press <kbd>backspace</kbd>, it moves the cursor *forwards* instead of backwards.  For example, here I tried to type `bash --version`, but accidentally omitted the `s` and had to backspace once to correct it:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ bash --veri sion
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)
…
```

You can see that the incorrect `i` is still present, followed by a space where I pressed <kbd>backspace</kbd>, followed by the rest of the command.  The command still *executes* correctly, which means the keystrokes are being interpreted correctly; they just aren't being *displayed* correctly.

Another case I've seen is that, upon resizing the PuTTY window, the prompt is redisplayed starting one line below the cursor position rather than over the top of the existing one.  For example, if I resize the window twice, I see the following without pressing any keys at all:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$
                 pi@raspberrypi:~$
                                  pi@raspberrypi:~$
```

Has anyone run into anything like this before or otherwise knows what's going on?  I haven't been successful finding a solution online and nothing in PuTTY's settings jumps out at me as a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not found a real explanation for the problem, but I did find a workaround.  The behavior only occurs when `TERM` is set to `xterm-color256`; changing it to `xterm-color` fixes the problem.

To change this permanently, launch PuTTY and load the saved session you want to change.  In the menu on the left, select Connection > Data.  There, you'll see the "Terminal-type string".  Change this to just `xterm-color`, then go back to Session and re-save your settings.

[image: Connection > Data]

Comment: Not sure where you got that `xterm-color256` at the first place, there's no such terminal definition and this string doesn't appear in PuTTY's source either. Did you mean `xterm-256color` instead?

Comment: @egmont Yeah, I see a terminfo file for `xterm-256color` as well, but `xterm-color256` is the default in PuTTY. Maybe I changed the default (incorrectly) some time ago and forgot.